# How to fill an online form that processes the values in the form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

How can I fill a cell in an HTML form that processes the textBox (possibly it converts a string value to float) after clicking on another cell? I am trying this line of code:

`document.getElementById("anID").value = 10;`

However, when trying to submit the form, it considers the specific cell empty. How can I identify what function is used that processes the textBox?

The HTML of the cell is the following:

```html
 <input      
   id="_exoik_requests_WAR_exoikonomov2portlet_:invoiceDialogForm:invQty_input"
   name="_exoik_requests_WAR_exoikonomov2portlet_:invoiceDialogForm:invQty_input"
   type="text" 
   onchange="PrimeFaces.ab({/*OBJECT - Removed for clarity*/});" 
   class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all pe-inputNumber ui-state-error" 
   role="textbox" 
   aria-disabled="false" 
   aria-readonly="false">
```

Comment: Show us your html for textBox that you are referring. Is it a text input or textarea or something else?

Comment: I have updated the question by including the html

Comment: Sorry for the unclear explanation. I am new in Javascript and HTML

Comment: `Element.value` is always a String. I don't understand your question, but think you want to cast the String like: `+Element.value`. Yes, just putting a `+` in front of a String will cast it unless concatenating with a String.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE], we are really only seeing part of the problem here.

Comment: Actually, what I need to do is to fill the value in this cell. However, it has an inner function that for example converts the value 10 to 10.00